# Marshalling Events Across Threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, marshalling

I imagine this may be marked as repetitious and closed, but I cannot for the life of me find a clear, concise answer to this question. All the replies and resources deal almost exclusively with Windows Forms and utilizing pre-built utility classes such as BackgroundWorker. I would very much like to understand this concept at its core, so I can apply the fundamental knowledge to other threading implementations.

A simple example of what I would like to achieve:

```
//timer running on a seperate thread and raising events at set intervals
//incomplete, but functional, except for the cross-thread event raising
class Timer
{
    //how often the Alarm event is raised
    float _alarmInterval;
    //stopwatch to keep time
    Stopwatch _stopwatch;
    //this Thread used to repeatedly check for events to raise
    Thread _timerThread;
    //used to pause the timer
    bool _paused;
    //used to determine Alarm event raises
    float _timeOfLastAlarm = 0;

    //this is the event I want to raise on the Main Thread
    public event EventHandler Alarm;

    //Constructor
    public Timer(float alarmInterval)
    {
        _alarmInterval = alarmInterval;
        _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        _timerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Initiate));
    }

    //toggles the Timer
    //do I need to marshall this data back and forth as well? or is the
    //_paused boolean in a shared data pool that both threads can access?
    public void Pause()
    {
        _paused = (!_paused);            
    }

    //little Helper to start the Stopwatch and loop over the Main method
    void Initiate()
    {
        _stopwatch.Start();
        while (true) Main();    
    }

    //checks for Alarm events
    void Main()
    {
        if (_paused && _stopwatch.IsRunning) _stopwatch.Stop();
        if (!_paused && !_stopwatch.IsRunning) _stopwatch.Start();
        if (_stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds > _timeOfLastAlarm)
        {
            _timeOfLastAlarm = _stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds;
            RaiseAlarm();
        }
    }
}
```

Two questions here; primarily, how do i get the event to the main thread to alert the interested parties of the Alarm event.

Secondarily, regarding the Pause() method, which will be called by an object running on the main thread; can i directly manipulate the Stopwatch that was created on the background thread by calling _stopwatch.start()/_stopwatch.stop(). If not, can the main thread adjust the _paused boolean as illustrated above such that the background thread can then see the new value of _paused and use it?

I swear, I've done my research, but these (fundamental and critical) details have not made themselves clear to me yet.

Disclaimer: I am aware that there are classes available that will provide the exact particular functionality that I am describing in my Timer class. (In fact, I believe the class is called just that, Threading.Timer) However, my question is not an attempt to help me implement the Timer class itself, rather understand how to execute the concepts that drive it.

Comment: I think what you need to look for is not a way to marshall/pass the event across threads, but for a way to signal one thread, when something happens on the other. This is a slightly different concept, meaning the listening thread will also either block or actively poll/loop untill the singal is received.

Comment: @YavgenyP That is precisely what I want to do, have ThreadTwo signal ThreadOne to DoWork. I've always used Events to signal unrelated code to do something, so that was how I described my intent. Forgive me though, I'm not sure I see the difference between marshaling and event versus marshaling another type of data (signal).

Comment: What you seem to want are the concepts of Semaphores and Mutex's.  methods with which to signal events across threads.  The objects themselves are shared between the threads so that changes to them in one can be seen in the other. This allows you to block one thread until the other does something.  You can also do similar things with events and delegates, i think...although I must admit I've never actually tried that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Synchronous Event Handler thread execution in non-Win Form C# app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444668/synchronous-event-handler-thread-execution-in-non-win-form-c-sharp-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: im writing this here because theres not enough space on comments, this is of course not a complete, nor half a complete answer:

> I've always used Events to signal unrelated code to do something, so that was how I described my intent. Forgive me though, I'm not sure I see the difference between marshaling and event versus marshaling another type of data (signal).

Conceptually both can be treated as events. The difference between using provided sync/signalining objects and trying to implement something like this by urself, is who and how gets the job done.

An event in .net is just a delegate, a list of pointers to methods that should be executed when the provider of the event fires it.
 What youre talking about (marshalling the event), if i understand you correctly, is sharing the event object *when* something happens, while the concept of signalig usually talks about an object which is shared *to start with*, and both threads "know" something happened by checking its state either manualy or automatily (relying on provided tools by both .net and windows).

In the most basic scenario, you can implement such a signaling concept by using a `boolean` variable, with one thread constantly looping to check if the value of the `boolean` is true, and another setting to such, as a way to signal something happend. The different signaling tools provided by .NET do this in a less resource-wasting maner, by also not executing the waiting thread, as long as theres no signal (the boolean equals to false), but conceptually, it is the same idea.

Comment: Despite the fact that this is 'not a complete, nor half a complete answer' it gave me exactly what I need. Instantiate an object, run a process within that object in a separate thread, use the Main Thread to check in on a value that signals a change, completion, etc. This makes a lot more sense, since my follow up question to my original would have been 'Where would the event's implemented method execute relative to the rest of the main threads code body.' Now, it is clear, it executes wherever the main thread checks in. Perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot magically execute code on an existing thread.
Instead, you need the existing thread to explicitly execute your code, using a thread-safe data structure to tell it what to do.

This is how `Control.Invoke` works (which is in turn how `BackgroundWorker` works).
WiinForms runs a message loop in `Application.Run()` which looks roughly like this:

```
while(true) {
    var message = GetMessage();  //Windows API call
    ProcessMessage(message);
}
```

`Control.Invoke()` sends a Windows message (using thread-safe message passing code within Windows) telling it to run your delegate.  `ProcessMessage` (which executes on the UI thread) will catch that message and execute the delegate.

If you want to do this yourself, you will need to write your own loop.  You can use the new thread-safe Producer-Consumer collections in .Net 4.0 for this, or you can use a delegate field (with `Interlocked.CompareExchange`) and an `AutoResetEvent` and do it yourself.

Comment: The code snippet you provided is very confusing to me, but I suspect it may be because it is incomplete/oversimplified. That loop would appear to do nothing, not even draw the current UI, if there were no messages. Maybe there is always a message though. If ThreadOne creates and starts ThreadTwo, but then has to enter a loop to listen for ThreadTwo's information, I see no benefit of executing code on a second Thread; it's not parallel in any manner at that point. I suppose there could be a method Listen() executed for every cycle of ThreadOne that checks for information from ThreadTwo?

Comment: @Michael: The UI gets drawn by `WM_PAINT` messages.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want a full message loop, but rather a producer-consumer-style setup.

Comment: I see. So the UI thread dedicates itself to that loop and the actions associated with the messages it receives, and then another thread(s) consistently provide the information needed to perform it's work. The other thread will send a 'Draw()' message with draw data, regardless of whether or not that data has changed between cycles.

Comment: @Michael: No; Windows does all of that.  For more info on how that works, read Raymond Chen or MSDN Win32 docs.

Comment: Oh! I think I begin to understand. The threads communicate through a Windows service, which acts as a router, receiving messages from one thread and sending them to the appropriately interested ones? I will read the suggested materials. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: I'm so glad you mentioned that's how Control.Invoke(). It totally made it click why you get that InvalidOperationException exception "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created." I'm guess that the winforms message loop doesn't start running until there is a window handle.